# Ehcache NullPointerException by getEhcache()

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, ehcache

I am trying to cache the result of a DAO, following [this JDBC Caching chapter](http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/jdbc). Unfortunately, I am getting the following `NullPointerException`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    my.package.EhCacheWrapper.getCache(EhCacheWrapper.java:39)
```

Line 39 refers to the first try accessing an `Ehcache` instance, returned by this line

```
return cacheManager.getEhcache(cacheName);
```

where `getEhcache(cacheName)` returns `null`. The object reference id of `cacheManager` always stays the same. My project uses Spring 3.0.5 and Ehcache 2.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discarded the [self-implemented](http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/jdbc#the-example-files) `EhcacheWrapper` and used the `EhCacheFactoryBean` provided by Spring.

```
<bean id="inventoryCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
    <property name="cacheName" value="pets" />
</bean>
```

Note that I had to get things working for Spring 3.0.5. You can use [Spring Cache Abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) from Spring 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `cacheManager` has not been initialised and is in fact `null`.

Comment: How is this an answer to his problem?

Comment: It is indicating that it is not `getEhcache(cacheName)` that returns null, there is a problem with his setup in the `applicationContext.xml` resulting in the `cacheManager` reference never having been injected/created.

Comment: The CacheManager has been initialized but its method `getEhcache` returns `null`.

Comment: Not if you get an error on that line. If `cacheManager` was initialized, you wouldn't get an NPE, the method would return `null`.

Comment: @gustafc You are right. The `NullPointerException` happened when trying to access the returned value. I will update my question.